# Display Pseudo element above parent when parent's overflown is hidden

Tags: html, css

```css
div {
  margin: 50px;
  position: relative;
  background-color: red;
  width: 200px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 2px solid black; 
}

div::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  background-color: green;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  top: -25px;
  left:50px;

  border: 2px solid black; 
}

div.overflow-hidden {
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div>1st</div>
<div class="overflow-hidden">2nd</div>
```

1st case: as expected.

2nd case[overflow-hidden]: Middle part of top and bottom border should be green. Looks like circle is not above its parent `div`'s border. Is there any way to make it above it? Whats happening here? Will the z-index work?

Comment: z-index not work.

Comment: Z-index don't work, when parent's is set to overflow hidden;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Why is this happening?

This is because `overflow: hidden;` clips the content to the content box.

> **hidden**
>
> Content is clipped if necessary to fit the content box. No scrollbars
>   are provided.

MDN Web docs - *https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/overflow*

This can be seen in the first example below as I have changed the `border` to be transparent.

### What can you do?

One way to get around this would be to apply the border using an absolutely positioned pseudo element instead of to the containing `div`.

```css
div {
  background-color: red;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 50px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
}

div::after {
  background-color: green;
  border: 2px solid black;
  border-radius: 100%;
  content: '';
  height: 100px;
  left: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  top: -25px;
  width: 100px;
}

div.overflow-with-border {
  border: 2px solid transparent;
}

div.overflow-with-pseudo {
  padding: 2px;
}

div.overflow-with-pseudo::before {
  border: 2px solid black;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  content: '';
  height: 100%;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="overflow-with-border">1st</div>
<div class="overflow-with-pseudo">2nd</div>
```